# Navigator.jumpTo without using a Route Stack

Tags: react-native

Why does Navigator.jumpTo require require the use of a route stack when Navigator.push does not?

I want to be able to jumpTo and back from any route/scene in my application.

Navigator.push and Navigator.pop work fine EXCEPT that I need to have my main scene remain mounted.

If I use Navigator.jumpTo and Navigator.jumpBack, the main scene remains mounted, but I have to use a route stack, which sometimes forces me to go back through multiple scenes to get back to my main scene.

The only solution I can think of is to dynamically manipulate the route stack before I jumpTo a new route, but this seems inelegant and unnecessary.

Or perhaps I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1):

*This is because of the `jumpTo` function have some problems,you can change it.*

> Open `you-project\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\CustomComponents\Navigator\Navigator.js`.

Change this code(In line 1031):

```
jumpTo: function(routeName) {
    var destIndex = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.routeStack.length; i++) {
        if (this.state.routeStack[i]["name"] === routeName) {
            destIndex = i;
        }
    }
    invariant(
        destIndex !== -1,
        'Cannot jump to route that is not in the route stack'
    );
    this._jumpN(destIndex - this.state.presentedIndex);
},
```

Now you can use `jumpTo` like `navigator.jumpTo("Home")`.